# Change product category once the order status get completed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I want to apply new category to product once the order status get "completed" in WooCommerce. Let's say that the Product is in (category A) and I want to apply (category B) on order status "completed".

Is there any way to do this?

I found couple of tutorials but don't know how to combine them:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/automatically-add-posts-to-a-category-conditionally

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/woocommerce-on-order-complete-insert-quantity-data-into-custom-database-table

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

> As you want to change the woocommerce category for a product, you should use [**`wp_set_object_terms()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) native WordPress function that accept either the category ID or slug **with `'product_cat'` taxonomy parameter** and **NOT** `'category'`.

The **`woocommerce_order_status_completed`** hook is classically used to fire a callback function when order change to status completed.

This is the code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'add_category_to_order_items_on_competed_status' 10, 1);

function add_category_to_order_items_on_competed_status( $order_id ) {

    // set your category ID or slug
    $your_category = 'my-category-slug'; // or $your_category = 123; 
    
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $product_item ) {
        $product_id = $product_item->get_product_id();
        
        wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $your_category, 'product_cat' );
    }
}
```

Or you can use also **`woocommerce_order_status_changed`** hook with a conditional function that will filter order "completed" status:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'add_category_to_order_items_on_competed_status' 10, 1);

function add_category_to_order_items_on_competed_status( $order_id ) {

    // set your category ID or slug
    $your_category = 'my-category-slug'; // or $your_category = 123; 
    
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    if ( $order->has_status( 'completed' ) ) {
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $product_item ) {
            $product_id = $product_item->get_product_id();

            wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $your_category, 'product_cat' );
        }
    }
}
```

*This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme or theme.*

**This code is tested and fully functional.**

Comment: HI, When i pasted the code in functions.pho it gives an error in first line and second line of your code. I think the word (function) is missing in second line but don't tknow why it gives an error on first line of your code.. add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'add_category_to_order_items_on_competed_status' 10, 1);

Comment: Also I am using a grouped product, can we check if the first product in group list is completed and then changed the category?

Comment: @user3814097  Sorry I can't test with grouped product as I haven't use this feature yet. The best way would be to **ask an other question including the code of this answer**. You will get better chance to solve it for grouped products.

Comment: I mean the code you provided works fine but I also want to apply a condition so if another product is true then it should apply the category. That is a hard-code product by Id '3334'.

Comment: I think we need to add something on this line of your code to check for two products... $item_id = $item['product_id']

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do any thing after order complete then you have to use `woocommerce_order_status_completed` action, and to add category you have to use [wp_set_object_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms). So in your case this function should work.

```
function add_cat_product($order_id) {
    $post_categories = array(); //Array of category IDs.
    $append = FALSE; // If true, categories will be appended to the post. If false, categories will replace existing categories.
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        //$product_name = $item['name'];
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        $term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $post_categories, 'product_cat', $append);
        if ( is_wp_error( $term_taxonomy_ids ) ) {
            // There was an error somewhere and the terms couldn't be set.
        } else {
            // Success! The post's categories were set.
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'add_cat_product' );
```

Comment: Hi Raunak - Thanks for the answer but where do I define [category B] in the above code?

Comment: You have to add the category id in `$post_categories` variable. For example if your category B id is 12 then you have to write `$post_categories = array(12);`.

Comment: Do I also need to define product ID in this line  $product_id = $item['product_id']; ?

Comment: No, it will be dynamic. if use buy a product then after order complete that product will be added to the cat B.

Comment: Hi Raunak - The code you provided doesn't do anything when the order is marked completed in the back-end? Can you suggest anything else. thx!

Comment: @user3814097: I have **update my answer** with new action, so try it.